# How to evaluate observable or computed array in react mobx using console.log

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have a computed array that I manage to iterate through without problems like so :

```
<select>
  {releaseDefault.map(ref =>
    <option key={ref.id}>{ref.name}</option>
  )};
</select>
```

I'm trying to evaluate this array in the render method using  `autorun`

```
  autorun(() => {
      console.log(releaseDefault); //value is a computed array.
    });
```

result:

```
(4) [{…}, Proxy, Proxy, Proxy]
0 Proxy[[Handler]]:Object[[Target]]:Object[[IsRevoked]]:false
1 Proxy[[Handler]]:Object[[Target]]:Object[[IsRevoked]]:false
2 Proxy[[Handler]]:Object[[Target]]:Object[[IsRevoked]]:false
3 Proxy[[Handler]]:Object[[Target]]:Object[[IsRevoked]]:false
```

Question : how do I access the actual array rather than the above result ?
Having the same issue for the actual observable.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to evaluate the observable array by **evaluating the class containing this array**, like so:

```
import { Map as iMap } from "immutable";
render(){

let rc = iMap(referenceClass)
console.log("Values of observables in class 'referenceClass' ",rc.toJS());

return (
...
```

Don't forget to install immutable:

```
npm i immutable
```

Let me know if you've got a better way...

Answer (score 0):

mobx 6.2.0 comes with it's own `toJS()` so immutable is not needed.

I'm unsure about previous versions

`import { toJS } from 'mobx'` does the trick